# Как составить SQL запрос: подсчет кол-во записей за год помесячно

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица (info) с данными: info_id, info_text, info_date_start(формат DATE) и тд.
Задача: подсчитать кол-во опубликованных записей в каждом месяце за текущий год.

Общий запрос делаю так:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(info_date_start) FROM info'; 
$result = $connect->query($sql);  
$count = $result->fetch_array(); 
$count = $count[0];
```

А как получить массив с кол-вом записей за каждый месяц не могу разобраться. 
Пробовал так:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(info_date_start) FROM info GROUP BY MONTH(info_date_start)';
```

Выдает:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["COUNT(info_date_start)"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Подскажите как составить запрос.

Comment: запросить у БД все строчки, а не только одну?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще как вы сделали должно работать , но надо обойти массив

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(info_date_start) FROM info GROUP BY MONTH(info_date_start)'; 
$result = $connect->query($sql);  
while($count = $result->fetch_array()){
    print_r($count);
}
```

Но посчитает по месяцам за все годы

Comment: Обошел массив. Получил: 'Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 37 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 37 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [COUNT(info_date_start)] => 1 )'

Comment: На каждом обходе получаем массив с двумя элементами, я правильно трактую увиденное? Не могу пока понять всей картины. Как теперь эти значения получить в один единый массив, чтобы можно было работать с данными (выводить\подставлять)?

Comment: Во время обхода цикла и работайте , или вам нужен доступ к массиву ?   не понял какой драйвер вы используете но судя по методу устаревший , в PDO например есть PDOStatement::fetchAll . Можете просто собрать массив , в цикл добавте $arr[] = $count ; в arr будет весь массив

Comment: Всё разобрался, спасибо огромное.

Comment: Для тех кто будет искать решение в будущем, решение поставленной задачи: `$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(info_date_start) FROM info WHERE YEAR(info_date_start) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY MONTH(info_date_start)'; 
    $result = $connect->query($sql);  
    while($count = $result->fetch_array()){
          $count = $count[0];
          $arr[] = $count;
    } `

Answer (score 2):

Тонкость в том, что [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) выдает просто номер месяца. То есть в другом году опять будут те же месяцы. Я думаю вы не хотели суммировать число записей в о всех январях любого года :)
Поэтому надо либо указать в условии WHERE конкретный год:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, MONTH(info_date_start) AS mnth 
FROM info 
WHERE YEAR(info_date_start) = 2016
GROUP BY 2"; 
$result = $connect->query($sql);  
while($count = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($count);
}
```

либо группировать по паре год-месяц, например так:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
  YEAR(info_date_start) AS yer, 
  MONTH(info_date_start) AS mnth,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM info 
GROUP BY 1, 2 WITH ROLLUP"; 
$result = $connect->query($sql);  
while($count = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(info_date_start) , COUNT(info_date_start) 
FROM your_table
WHERE info_date_start >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY MONTH(info_date_start)
```